# Using CasperJS and sitespeed.io together

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to use sitespeed.io to measure a page that is behind a login form (the basic auth within sitespeed.io does not work with this site).

I was able to create a casperjs script that can log into the application, but I'm not sure how to then pass this off to sitespeed.io.  They both use PhantomJS in the background so I think it would be possible, but they are essentially two separate processes.  I.e.: First run CasperJS to log in and then run sitespeed.io to measure the site.

When I run sitespeed.io it doesn't know about the CasperJS process.  Has anyone done something similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the selenium-webdriver npm module for this (I was getting unreliable results with CasperJS).  The first script does the login and then it is easy enough to call sitespeed.io afterwards to run the analysis.